# How to play protected AAC tracks via Sonos?

Tags: itunes, wifi, music

I have many songs I bought from iTunes that are in the old Protected AAC format.  They play find from my iPhone or from my computer to attached speakers.  I would like to stream them over my home WiFi network.  I tried some Sonos speakers with their app, which could play everything in my library except these.  Is there a way to stream them?

Comment: https://en.community.sonos.com/setting-up-sonos-228990/apple-itunes-protected-aac-audio-file-how-to-import-to-sonos-music-source-6735921 might offer some clues